# "coming out of the head"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

A character in the movie *The Kingdom* says:

> They celebrated her graduation at the IHOP until some townie called Janet something. I don't know, something not very nice. So the townie didn't see Fran **coming out of the head**, but he definitely felt Fran's uppercut shatter his jaw.

What does "coming out of the head" mean here? It doesn't appear to be idiomatic, according to Google. For a second I thought it was "coming out ahead", but all sources point to "coming out of the head".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The head" is probably the bathroom (sorry, US lingo, ... = "toilet"). It's slang. I think it originated in the Navy.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/head) lists definition 12b. of "head" as "a ship's toilet."